# O.O.P and Class Properties

Tags: oop

I'm new to O.O.P and would like advice on best practice.

Say for example I have a Course class which holds course information, and a Location class which holds location details. Classes have corresponding repository classes. Now, each Course HAS A location which I have added Location as a property.

When I am pulling the details of a Course from the database, is it best practice to:
A – Populate the Location object from within the CourseRepository Class meaning SQL would return both course and location details
B – Only populate Course object, returning the Location ID, then use the LocationRepository class to find the location details

I’m leaning more towards B as this is a separation of responsibility, however, the thing that’s getting me is performance. Say I need a List instead which returns a result of 50. Would it be wise to query SQL 50 times to seek location details? Would appreciate your thoughts on this.

Lewis

Comment: From real world view, I'd consider a `Course` with a `Location` to be a `Session`. If you keep in mind that you may have to re-schedule one (or more) instance(s) of your course to a different location, this should influence your design.

Answer (score 0):

In part, you're thinking in a wrong conceptual direction. It should be: one location can have many courses, not the reciprocal.

That said, theoretical, a Course domain object should not contain a location as class member, but just a location id. On the other hand, a domain object Location could contain an array of Course objects as class member, if needed. You see the difference?

Now, in your case, indeed pass a Location as argument to a Course object. And, in the Course repository, define a method like `fetchCoursesWithLocations()` in which you run only one sql query to fetch 50 courses TOGETHER WITH the corresponding location details - based on your criterias - into an array. Then loop through the records array. For each of the record item build a Location object and a Course object (to which you pass the Location object as argument). Then pass each so created Course object to another array holding all resulting Course objects, or to a CourseCollection object (which I recommend). In the end return the Courses array (or the CourseCollection content) from the method.

Now, all is somehow too complex to present in here. But I'll give you here three great articles (a serie) which will make the whole process very clear to you. You'll find out in there how a `CourseCollection` should see, too. In the articles (from the second one upwards), it is used the term "Mapper", which I'm pretty sure it's the same as your "repository". Actually, there are two abstraction layers for data access in the db: mappers and repositories. Plus the adapters.

Look to the part with the `PostMapper` and the `CommentMapper`. They are the parallels to your `CourseRepository`, respectively your `LocationRepository`. The same roles have `Post` and `Comment` models (domain objects!): as parallels to your `Course` and `Location`.

The articles are:

1. **[Building a Domain Model - An Introduction to Persistence
   Agnosticism](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-domain-model/)**
2. **[Building a Domain Model - Integrating Data Mappers](https://www.sitepoint.com/integrating-the-data-mappers/)**
3. **[Handling Collections of Aggregate Roots - the Repository Pattern](https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-collections-of-aggregate-roots/)**